# Background image and after background color in one div

Tags: css

Example code:

```
<div class="ex">Bla bla bla bla</div>
```

In the top will be background-image and after when it'll finish display the background-image it'll disply a background-color.

Somthing like that:

```
[Image] text
[color] more text
[color] mor text..
```

How do I do it with CSS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
background: url("img/folder/file.jpg") repeat-x #000000;
```

Change the hex to whatever color you need.

Comment: And if i want in the bottom another background-image? can I do again (after the color) "url("img/folder/file.jpg") repeat-x" ?

Comment: In CSS3 there's an easier way to do it but you run into compatibility issues there. You'll need to put a div inside that div `<div class="ex"><div class="child_ex"></div></div>` - set up background properties for child_ex and now you have an another background.

Answer (score 0):

try to use background image repeat property:

```
background-repeat: repeat | repeat-x | repeat-y | no-repeat
```